# Pertinence of void pointers

Tags: c++, refactoring

Looking through a colleague's code, I see that some of its handles are stored as void pointers.

```
// Class header
void* hSomeSdk;

// Class implementation
hSomeSdk = new SomeSDK(...);
((SomeSDK*)hSomeSdk)->DoSomeWork();
```

Now I know that sometimes handles are void pointers because it may be unknown before runtime what will be the actual type of the handle. Or that it can help when we need to share the pointer without revealing its actual structure. But this does not seem to be the case in my situation: it will always be SomeSDK and it is not shared outside the class where it is created. Also the author of this code is gone from the company.

Are there other reasons why it would make sense to have it be a void pointer?

Comment: If it's internal to the class, then there is no good reason at all. A handle is a nebulous concept.

Comment: `hSomeSdk` is a member of a class by any chance? Some programmers just aren't aware they can forward declare classes in order to define pointer to them. The colleague may have wanted to avoid including a header they otherwise don't need in your own header file.

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand the reason for the void pointer in this case would be to ask your colleague why they are using a void pointer there.  Stands out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is indeed a member.

Comment: @Eljay Sadly the colleague left the company.

Comment: Based solely on the shown code there is no reason for it, and it simply offers fertile breeding grounds for bugs. There maybe other reasons for it, such as interfacing with a C library. But, in general, pure, modern C++ code never has any need for void pointers.

Comment: also in the situation you describe you need to know what is the actual type, otherwise you cannot do much with the `void*`. I dont think there is any reason to use `void*` other than interfacing legacy / c apis

Comment: @AlexMillette Based solely on the shown code, it's not so sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a member variable, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say your colleague wanted to minimize dependencies. Including the header for `SomeSDK` is probably undesirable just to define a pointer. The colleague may have had one of two reasons as far as I can see from the code you show:

1. They just didn't know they can add a forward declarations like `class SomeSDK;` to allow defining pointers. Some programmers just aren't aware of it.
2. They *couldn't* forward declare it. If `SomeSDK` is not a class, but a type alias (aka `typedef`), then it's not possible to forward declare it exactly. One can only declare the class it aliases, but that in turn may be an implementation detail that's hard to keep track of. Even the standard library has a similar problem, that is why it provides [`iosfwd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) to make forward declaring standard stream types easier.

If the code is peppered with casts of this handle, then the design should have been reworked ages ago. Otherwise, if it's in one place (or a few at most) only, I can see why the people maintaining it could live with it peacefully.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

If I had to guess, the ex-colleague was unfamiliar with *forward declarations* and thus didn't know they could still do `SomeSDK*` in the header without including the entire `SomeSDK` definition.

Given the constraints you've mentioned, the only thing this pattern achieves is to eliminate some type safety, make the code harder to read/maintain, and generate a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` were popular and needed back in C. They are convenient in the sense that they can be easily cast to anything. If you need to cast from `double*` to `char*`, you have to make a mid cast to `void*`.

The problem with `void*` is that they are too flexible: they do not convey intentions of the writer, making them very unsafe especially in big projects.

In Object Oriented Design it is popular to create abstract interface classes (all members are virtual and not implemented) and make pointers to such classes and then instantiate various possible implementation depending on the usage.

However, nowadays, it is more recommended to work with templates (main advantage of C++ over other languages), as those are much faster and enable more compile-time optimization than OOD allowed. Unfortunately, working with templates is still a huge hassle - they have more complicated syntax and it is difficult to convey intentions of the writer to users about restrictions and demands of the template parameters (Concepts TS that solves this problem decently will be available in C++20 - currently there is only SFINAE, a horrible temporary solution from 20 years ago; while Reflection TS, that will greatly enhance generic programming in C++, is unlikely to be available even in C++23).